# Equivalent GroovyMBean in java

Tags: java, groovy, jmx

I have some JMX configuration in my server. Now when I want to get it I call this from groovy:

```
GroovyMBean mbean = new GroovyMBean(server, application)
mbean.invokeMethod(function,parameter)
```

What is equivalent of `GroovyMBean` in java because now I want to call this configuration from java code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, this code snippet will be used in Java to connect to JMXServer.

```
     JMXConnector jmxConnector = null;
            MBeanServerConnection mbeanConn = null;
            try {
                String url = "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://" + this.server + ":" + this.port + "/jmxrmi";
                JMXServiceURL serviceUrl;

                serviceUrl = new JMXServiceURL(url);
                jmxConnector = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serviceUrl, null);
                mbeanConn = jmxConnector.getMBeanServerConnection();
}catch(Exception e)
{
}
finally
{
//close jmx connector.
}
```

Comment: this is just connection what is in my example server Now I dont know how to continue to get MBean and invoke some method

Answer (score 0):

Sorry so late. I just ran into similar issue. No mBean class, but there are generic object classes. Also your service URL is missing part. ObjectName is the mbean name and methodName is the function to invoke.

```
MBeanServerConnection connection = null;
HashMap<String,String[]> jmxEnv = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
String[] credentials = new String[2];
credentials[0] = JMX_User;
credentials[1] = JMX_Password;
jmxEnv.put(JMXConnector.CREDENTIALS,credentials);

JMXServiceURL serverUrl = null;

serverUrl = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi://"+JMX_Server+":"+JMX_Port+"/jndi/rmi://"+JMX_Server+":"+JMX_Registry_Port+"/server");
connection = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(serverUrl, jmxEnv).getMBeanServerConnection();
ObjectName beanName = null;
beanName = new ObjectName("ObjectName");
Object[] params = new Object[1];
params[0]=fileName;
String[] signature = new String[0];
connection.invoke(beanName, "methodName", params, signature);
```